# how to enabled gzip in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, gzip

i want gzip css and js file in website. and use this code in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
```

analyze my website with gtmetrix.com site, but get:

```
Compressing the following resources with gzip could reduce their transfer size by 63.4KiB (77% reduction).

Compressing http://mysite.com/ could save 30.6KiB (74% reduction).
Compressing http://mysite.com/WebResource.axd?d=TdZvTxV1RZCMol6igoEA7XxfdqcWpTRlYuCxfymg_ruU4xc1NuSqLn7bduKh3WyPwSYX0g86d6fEJ3SVBdeWi5FBnMpKfcO7aaFoqvmTo_c1&t=634970873020000000 could save 17.5KiB (80% reduction).
Compressing http://mysite.com/main.css could save 14.8KiB (80% reduction).
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938713/gzip-compression-on-iis-7-5-is-not-working#answer-6967240), the compression happens in a background process on a different thread, so it won't be available on the first request. Also, keep in mind this is not an ASP.NET feature, but an IIS feature.

There is also an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091536/gzip-compression-is-not-working-on-iis-7-please-help) that shows a valid configuration.

**Tip:** You may also want to check into using [bundling and minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).

Answer (score 0):

For the dynamictypes in your web config you will also need to install the dynamic compression module in IIS else these won't do anything.

Answer (score -1):

I found a code that u should use after in web.config file in your file manager:

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

I used it now in my website: [www.irpolymer.com](http://www.irpolymer.com) but in gtmetrix shows that my gzip is disable, I think it will fix tomorrow.